# How do I combine multiple values into a single string?

Tags: delphi, listbox

I'm trying to learn Delphi and I'm currently making a game. I used to know a bit Pascal, but I know nothing about Delphi. I made this game in Pascal a few years ago. It contains a line like this:

```
writeln(turn,'  ',input,'   ',die[turn],'  ',wou[turn]);
```

Basically it is meant to show up the calculated results for an user input, with a few spaces between those numbers (all those variables are numbers except "input", which is a string).

I'm trying to display the results similarly in Delphi. Though it would be best to use a table, I have no idea how to use one, so I tried with a listbox. But the items.add procedure does not work like Pascal's `writeln`, thus I'm currently stuck.

I'm a new, first-time learner, so please make things easy to understand for me.

Answer (score 7):

Use the [`Format`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.SysUtils.Format) function,  from the `SysUtils` unit. It returns a string that you can use anywhere you can use a string:

```
// Given these values for turn, input, die[turn], and wou[turn]
turn := 1;
input := 'Whatever';
die[turn] := 0;
wou[turn] := 3;

procedure TForm1.UpdatePlayerInfo;
var
  PlayerInfo: string;
begin
  PlayerInfo := Format('%d %s %d %d', [turn, input, die[turn], wou[turn]]);

  // PlayerInfo now contains '1 Whatever 0 3'

  ListBox1.Items.Add(PlayerInfo);  // Display in a listbox
  Self.Caption := PlayerInfo;      // Show it in form's title bar
  ShowMessage(PlayerInfo);         // Display in a pop-up window
end;
```

You can always, of course, go directly to the `ListBox` without the intermediate string variable:

```
  ListBox1.Items.Add(Format('%d %s %d %d', [turn, input, die[turn], wou[turn]]));
```

The `%d` and `%s` in first part of the `Format` call are **format strings**, where `%d` represents a placeholder for an integer and `%s` represents a placeholder for a string. The documentation talks about format strings [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.SysUtils.Format#Format_Strings).

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is String Concatenation (adding of multiple strings to form a single new string):

```
// Given these values for turn, input, die[turn], and wou[turn]
turn := 1;
input := 'Whatever';
die[turn] := 0;
wou[turn] := 3;

ListBox1.Items.Add(IntToStr(turn)+' '+input+' '+IntToStr(die[turn])+' '+IntToStr(wou[turn]));
```

ie. addding together the various elements:

```
IntToStr(turn) // The Integer variable "turn" converted to a string
+' ' // followed by a single space
+input // followed by the content of the string variable "input"
+' ' // followed by a single space
+IntToStr(die[turn]) // element no. "turn" of the integer array "die" converted to a string
+' ' // followed by a single space
+IntToStr(wou[turn]) // element no. "turn" of the integer array "wou" converted to a string
```

to form a single continous string value, and passing that value to the "Add" method of the ListBox's Items property.

Comment: I don't like that, because it a) is harder to read and maintain, and b) requires three separate calls to `IntToStr` and then placement of the space characters around each returned value. It also makes localization impossible. The `Format` function can just be passed a `resourcestring` that it can modify, and therefore can be changed very easily. (Not downvoting, but explaining why I didn't recommend that method.)

Comment: The plus side of this is that it is statically type safe. Not that big a deal in practice.

Comment: @KenWhite: "harder to read and maintain" is a subjective term. I find it easier to read, as I can see which values are placed where as I read the expression from left to right. The "Format" method means that I have to scan back and forth between the format string and the parameter list to see which values are placed where in the string... YMMV...

Comment: thanks, HeartWare. I tried this method before I post the question here, but somehow it always result in a conversion error of some sort that I can't understand. Still don't know why :)